# javascript understanding cookies indepth

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, express-session, js-cookie

In my frontend react application, I am trying to check if a session cookie exists, as this will help me decide whether to show a login page (if no session cookie exists or invalidated), or show content page.

The backend express-session middleware sets a cookie with a name "connect.sid".  When I query the presence of this cookie with js-cookie, it shows as **undefined**.  But I know this cookie exists. I also created another cookie programmatically from the browser console.  While I am able to successfully query the cookie which I set programmatically from browser console window, I am unable to find the first one.

Here is the screenshot to show the available cookies.
[image]

And here is my test for both cookies from browser console.
[image]

I am unable to figure it out, why querying for "connect.sid" is failing. Can someone help me, where I am going wrong here...

Comment: What does `document.cookie` say in the console?

Comment: See the `HTTP` column. The entry is `HttpOnly` and JavaScript can't read that.

Comment: document.cookie returns "hello=world"

Comment: so, it means, I can't access a HTTP-ONLY cookie is it?  I am planning to do session availability detection in my react based front end app.  So, should I create my own javascript cookie?

Comment: That's a switch. You can disable it (server side) and it will make your app less secure. I usually use tokens (JWT as an example) and send a request to server in the app's bootstrap file. If server returns 200 status code then the user is logged-in (token is valid) and the app is initialized. Otherwise the login modal is shown.

Comment: ok, got it.  Then I prefer to set a client side cookie, after login success, which will have user name (but no other parameters). Thx.